# Why does cout not print extern "C" variable?

Tags: c++, c, solaris, extern, sunstudio

Consider the following code:

```
extern "C" {
    #include <lib.h>
}

#include <iostream>

int main() {

    unsigned char a='a';
    unsigned char b=some_struct_in_libh->unsignedchar;

    cout << a << " " << b << endl; //Prints only a

    printf("%u\n",b); //Prints b

    cout << static_cast<int>(b) << endl; //Also prints b

    return 0;
}
```

Why does it behave like this?

Comment: Since we neither know what `some_struct_in_libh` and what `unsignedchar` and all of their values are, we can only guess that it prints something, but you can not see it.

Comment: b is printed as what? Is it a valid character? Do you want it to be treated as a character (a string of one character) or as a number?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not printing only `a` at all. What you're seeing is instead that `cout` prints character type data as *characters* not as numbers. Your `b` is some character that's non-printable so `cout` is helpfully printing it as a blank space.

You found the solution by casting it to int.

EDIT: I'm pretty sure your printf is only working by chance because you told it to expect an unsigned int and gave it a character (different number of bytes).

Comment: printf works because in the case of a variable argument function, all types of "integral type" are converted to "int" unless they are larger. So the code is perfectly fine as is - but of course, it prints the unsigned value of the char, not the character itself which is correctly addressed in this answer.

Comment: Upvote for describing that cout prints character type data as _characters_, converting non-printable input to blanks. `printf("%c", b);` would likely display the garbage character.

Comment: The thing here was I was using an external library which created some classes with char as members, but instead of writing the ASCII to it, it wrote as if it was a 1-byte-int, if that makes sense.

Anyway, thanks for the help understanding printing.